# Repeated error in LinkedList

Tags: java, arrays, list

.. and by repeated, I mean repeated. I have a simple implementation of a list interface, functioning like a simple baby-version of the LinkedList.

I have the classes "Knoten"(means "knot" in German), MyLinkedList and, well, Main.

The Error my compiler tosses at me originates in class Knoten, line 35. 
But it doesn´t tell me what kind of error it is.

"at Knoten.nextN(Knoten.java:35)"

is all it says. A million times. My whole cmd window is filled with this line. I bet it printed this error message for more than hundred times, again and again. I tried to search for similar problems, but couldn´t really find anything useful because I don´t know which error to search for.

Why did my program crash?

Please help..

Knoten:

```
class Knoten<T> {
Knoten nachfolger; 
T t; 

public Knoten(T t){
    this.t = t;
    nachfolger = null; 
}

public void add(T tneu) {
    if (nachfolger != null) {
        nachfolger.add(tneu);
    }
    else {
        Knoten kneu = new Knoten(tneu);
        nachfolger = kneu;
    }
}

public Knoten giveNachfolger(){
    return nachfolger;
}

public T fuerIDGeben(int index, Knoten anfang) {
    if(index == nextN(anfang)){
        return (T) nachfolger.t;
    }
    return null;
}

private int nextN(Knoten k){
    int i = 1;
    if (nachfolger != null){
        i = i+1; 
        nextN(nachfolger);
    } else {}
    return i;
} }
```

MyLinkedList:

```
class MyLinkedList<T> implements MyList<T>{

Knoten anfang; 

public MyLinkedList<T>(){
    anfang = null;
}


public T get(int index){
    return (T) anfang.fuerIDGeben(index, anfang);
}

public void add(T t){
    if(anfang != null){
        anfang.add(t);
    } else {
        Knoten newKnoten = new Knoten(t);
        anfang = newKnoten; 
    }
}

public MyIterator<T> iterate(){
    return new MyLinkedIterator<T>(); 
}

private class MyLinkedIterator<T> implements MyIterator<T>{

public boolean hasNext(){
    if(anfang.giveNachfolger() != null){
        return true;
        }
    return false;
}

public T next(){
    if(anfang.giveNachfolger() != null){
        return (T) anfang.giveNachfolger().t;
    }
    return null;
}}}

    import java.util.*;
```

And Main:

```
class Main{

public static void main(String[] args){

MyList<Integer> list = new MyLinkedList<Integer>();

    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);

    System.out.println(list.get(0));

    MyIterator<Integer> it = list.iterate();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }


}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have infinite recursion in `nextN()`, leading to a stack overflow.

If you look closely at the implementation of `nextN()`, it repeatedly calls itself with the same argument. This continues until the JVM runs out of stack, at which point you get a `StackOverflowError`. The stack trace at the point of the exception will mention `nextN()` many times.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, +1.  You'll see that `nextN` doesn't actually use its argument `k` at all; which means you don't have any form of recursion on `k` - you just have an endless loop.

Comment: thanks a lot for your very quick reply. At least there are no error messages anymore. I tried to change my code as quamyoncu has described it, but am now confronted with a new problem: It returns "2" in infinite amounts. Can you explain why that may be the case?

Comment: @Aye: That's a separate problem (and therefore should be a separate question).

Comment: Okay... I´ll open a new one as soon as I got the time. Thank you for your help until now! ^^ I´d give you a vote-up but I don´t have much reputation yet, sorry. ^^;

Comment: You really should step through this with a debugger.  It would tell you immediately what is going wrong.

Comment: Alright, I´ll just slap it into an IDE in the future after researching and before asking then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using `k` in the `nextN` function, it always calls itself with the same parameter and brings infinite loops.

Instead of that, you should call the `nextN` function with the member variable of k in order to iterate over them.

If you have a link like:

k -> k.nachfolger -> k.nachfolger.nachfolger -> ...

Then you need to change your function with this:

```
private int nextN(Knoten k){
    if (k.nachfolger != null){
        return nextN(k.nachfolger) + 1;
    } 
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you really think that this would be fixed if you changed `nextN(nachfolger)` to `nextN(k)`?

Comment: OK, I've removed my downvote.  Perhaps you could explain what this new method does, and why you think it's the correct answer?

Comment: thanks a lot. ^^ There´s no error message anymore, yay! But now it keeps printing 2 all the time in infinite amounts. :?

Comment: In the iterator implementation, you should *really* iterate the iterator in somewhere. in `Main`, you are calling `it.next()` but it does not iterate it. For example you should do `anfang = anfang.nachfolger;` in the `next()` function.